# how to remove the name in email address

Tags: laravel-7

I have  email format like

```
iba@test.com
```

Expected output

```
@test.com
```

I need to remove the name after the mail id how can I do that I have tried str_replace but that does not give me a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Please try like this :

```
let string = "iba@test.com"
const result = `@${string.split('@')[1]}`
```

Answer (score 0):

using explode

```
$email= "iba@test.com"
$domain= explode("@",$email);

echo $domain[0]; // iba
echo $domain[1]; //test.com
```